# json.Unmarshal в map дерево

Tags: golang

Собственно есть JSON, нужно преобразовать его в дерево. И получить доступ к нодам. Пробовал так, Сразу уточню что структура JSON может меняться(какие-то поля могут добавляться или удаляться, но основные всегда неизменны)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    //"fmt"
)

//type nestedMaps map[string]nestedMaps

func main() {
    byt := []byte(`{
        "node1": {
            "value": "1",
            "node2": {
                "value": "2",
                "node4": {
                    "value": "4"
                }
            },
            "node3": {
                "value": "3"
            }
        }
    }`)

    var dat map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //fmt.Println(dat["node1"]["node2"]["node4"]["value"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Из `interface{}` нельзя взять значение без [утверждения типа](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). Так что вам придётся делать что-то типа

```
dat["node1"].(map[string]interface{})["node2"].(map[string]interface{})["node4"].(map[string]interface{})["value"]
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/oewoOonOXD.

Причём если внутри не тот тип, это будет паниковать. Так что если вы не хотите паниковать (а паниковать не стоит), то вам придётся использовать "безопасное утверждение типа" вида

```
node1, ok := dat["node1"].(map[string]interface{})
if !ok {
    return fmt.Errorf("bad type of node1: %T", dat["node1"])
}
// ...
```